# Sharing data with a name in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have added a share functionality in my app to share data like name, price,quantity and description. This is how I have achieved it...

```
let prodObj = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]
let name = prodObj.name
let price = prodObj.mrp
let qty = prodObj.quantity
let description = prodObj.descriptions

let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [name, price, qty, description], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

when I have shared like this in whatsapp, what the receiver gets is just something like Box,6,500 (if the name is box, quantity is 6 & price 500).

But when I am sending, I want the receiving party to get something like

```
Name: Box

Quantity: 6

Price: 500
```

instead of mere Box,6,500

How can I achieve this...?

Answer (score 4):

Send string for activity item like this `"Name: \(name)"`

```
let prodObj = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]
if let name = prodObj.name,
    let price = prodObj.mrp,
    let qty = prodObj.quantity,
    let description = prodObj.descriptions  {

    let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  ["Name: \(name)", "Price: \(price)", "Quantity: \(qty)", "Description: \(description)"], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: This does work @Emre Özdil but the receiver gets data in this format: Price: Optional(“580”) while it should have been just Price: 580

Comment: @D.M you can check value via ```if let``` or ```guard let``` for optional control

Comment: using if let gives this error..`Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NewProduct'`

Comment: Name, price, qty, and description are value of prodObj, therefore; we need 2 guard control

Comment: It worked @Emre Özdil with the initial answer it just had to be unwrapped like so...`["Name: \(name!)",...`

Comment: I don't know your data type; thus, I use ```if let ``` for all value. Maybe you try ```if let``` only name, price, qty, description values without prodObj.

Comment: .@Emre Özdil Do add your initial answer to accept...else the above answer might mislead others

Comment: Hey last edit code is correctly run? @D.M for question owner accepted solution

Answer (score 1):

just run the code:

```
    let name = "javed"
    let price = 700
    let qty = 77

    let finalString:String = "Name:" + name + "\n" + "Quantity:" + String(qty) + "\n" + "Price:" + String(price)
    print(finalString)
```

**Result:**

[image]

**or you have already string value then:**

[image]

Comment: still doesnt work @Mr.Javed Multani. It shows the same error

Comment: ok so check your object values. For now just give static values and test it.

Comment: Thanks for it,@D.M

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**:

```
let prodObj = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]
let name = prodObj.name
let price = prodObj.mrp
let qty = prodObj.quantity
let description = prodObj.descriptions

let finalString:String = "Name:" + name + "\n" + "Quantity:" + qty + "\n" + "Price:" + price 

let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [finalString], applicationActivities: nil)
```

**Result:**

```
Name: Box

Quantity: 6

Price: 500
```

**TESTED 100 % working**

Comment: This is definitely works let me know what is result?

Comment: it gives an error at let `finalString:String …` as `Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Comment: If you want string concatenation ```"Value: \(value)"``` is better than ```"Value: " + value```

Comment: hey gotta solution

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this.

```
let share : String = "Name: \(name) \nQuantity: \(qty) \nPrice: \(price)" 

let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems:  [share], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is instead of passing individual attributes like name price qty you create an array of string or dictionary using (key-value pair so you know which value is associate for which key) out of it and then pass the whole array, you can also check if a value exists, then only add it to the final array (based on your requirement)

```
let prodObj = newProdDetails[indexPath.row]

let name = prodObj.name ?? "" //this means if name is nil it will set empty string 
let price = prodObj.mrp ?? 0 
let qty = prodObj.quantity ?? 0
let description = prodObj.descriptions ?? ""

//create array from the data you get you can create a string like below
let finalArrayString =  ["Name: \(name)", "Price: \(price)", "Quantity: \(qty)", "Description: \(description)"]

//or create an array of the dictionary for using it late

let activityViewController:UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: finalArrayString , applicationActivities: nil)
```

Also, check if your prodObj is nil or not before using it, You can either return if its nill (base on your requirement)

Also understand why before just copy-pasting code from StackOverflow, as it will save your time later,